# How to extract a table from a website(url) using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The NIST dataset [website](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z29.html) contains some data of copper, how can I grab the table in the left (titled “HTML table format
“) from the website using a script of python.  And only perverse the numbers in the second and third columns as shown in picture below. And store all data into a .csv file. I tried codes below, but it failed to get the correct format of the table.

```
import pandas as pd

# URL of the table
url = "https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z29.html"

# Read the table into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, index_col=0)[0]
# Save the processed table to a CSV file
df.to_csv("nist_table.csv", index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

- `.droplevel([0,1])` to remove the unwanted header rows
- `.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` to remove the empty columns
- `.iloc[:,1:]` to select only specific 3 columns

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z29.html"

df = pd.read_html(url, header=[0,1,2,3])[1].droplevel([0,1], axis=1).dropna(axis=1, how='all').iloc[:,1:]
df
```

Comment: Hi @HedgeHog, your suggestion works. May I ask why here need parameter `header=[0,1,2,3]` and why use the returned second table `pd.read_html(url, header=[0,1,2,3])[1]`. I thought it should be `pd.read_html(url, header=[0,1,2,3])[0]`

Comment: `header=[0,1,2,3]` is used to get a cleaner first shot from the ugly HTML structure - Indexing with `[1]` is used because the table is nested in a nother table, that holds both sub tables and this container we do not like to extract - so we focus on what is needed. Hope this make sense for you?

Answer (score 0):

For parsing HTML documents **BeautifulSoup** is a great Python package to use, this with the **requests** library you can extract the data you want.

The code below should extract the desired data:

```
# import packages/libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

# define URL link variable, get the response and parse the HTML dom contents
url = "https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z29.html"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

# declare table variable and use soup to find table in HTML dom
table = soup.find('table')

# iterate over table rows (tr) and append table data (td) to rows list
rows = []
for i, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
    # only append data if its after 3rd row -> (MeV),(cm2/g),(cm2/g)
    if i > 3:
        rows.append([value.text.strip() for value in row.find_all('td')])

# create DataFrame from the data appended to the rows list
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# export data to csv file called datafile
df.to_csv(r"datafile.csv")
```